# sharepoint 2010 bcs external list column type as dropdown list, how to add default value?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have developed sharepoint 2010 external list by VS2010 through BCS, the external list is display data correctly except one column. I want this column to contain the the some strings from external source as its' default multiple choices value, any help will be appreciated!

I noticed that in VS2010 BCS, you can add the type descriptor as Collection, but how can this be converted to the default value of a list ?

Comment: Might get more help here:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/